# Victory Chart Issue with spacing and tick colors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, victory-charts

I want to create chart like that

[image]

I'm using victory chart to create that, I try to create similar chart like that but I'm facing problem with styling line removing axis line not ticklabels, giving color to tick values and spacing between bar.
That's the cart I created

[image]

and that's my code for that chart

```
 <VictoryChart
                width={moderateScale(320)}
                height={moderateScaleVertical(220)}>
                <VictoryGroup offset={15} colorScale={'qualitative'}>
                  <VictoryBar
                    data={[
                      {x: 1, y: 1},
                      {x: 2, y: 2},
                      {x: 3, y: 2},
                    ]}
                    animate={{
                      duration: 2000,
                      onLoad: {duration: 1000},
                    }}
                    cornerRadius={6}
                    style={{
                      data: {
                        fill: colors.skyBlue,
                      },
                    }}
                    barWidth={10}
                  />
                  <VictoryBar
                    data={[
                      {x: 1, y: 2},
                      {x: 2, y: 1},
                      {x: 3, y: 3},
                    ]}
                    animate={{
                      duration: 2000,
                      onLoad: {duration: 1000},
                    }}
                    cornerRadius={6}
                    style={{
                      data: {
                        fill: colors.primary,
                      },
                    }}
                    barWidth={10}
                  />
                  <VictoryAxis
                    tickValues={['Jun', 'Aug', 'Sep']}
                    style={{
                      tickLabels: {color: colors.blackL},
                      ticks: {color: colors.blackL},
                    }}
                  />
                  <VictoryAxis
                    dependentAxis={true}
                    tickValues={['₹0K', '₹10K', '₹20K', '₹30K']}
                    style={{
                      tickLabels: {fill: colors.blackL},
                      ticks: {stroke: colors.blackL},
                    }}
                  />
                </VictoryGroup>
              </VictoryChart>
```

can anyone tell me how to style it please

Answer (score 1):

To style the axis line itself you may apply `style.axis` to the axis block. To make it disappear apply transparent color to it by putting `{stroke: "transparent"}` into the block. Tick labels styling occurs in the `style.tickLabels` block.

For your case I came up with something like this:

```
<VictoryAxis
    tickValues={['Jun', 'Aug', 'Sep']}
    style={{
    axis: {stroke: "transparent"},
    tickLabels: {fill: "#cccccc"}
}} 
/>
```

I have also noticed styling not being applied in case `VictoryAxis` is used within `VictoryGroup`, so you may try to place axis outside the group.

Reference: https://formidable.com/open-source/victory/docs/victory-axis#style